# Def Win() with multiple options

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm in the process of learning Python and recreating an old program I made in Visual Basic from memory.

Most things are working properly, but I know there has to be a better way to declare a winner. The objective is to have 2-4 teams buzzing in and gaining score for questions. The team with the highest score wins.

Right now this is what the code for winning looks like, but I feel like it is very messy and must be a better way.

```
elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
    if Team1Point > Team2Point and Team1Point > Team3Point and Team1Point > Team4Point:
        Win = True
        win.play()
        while Win:
            gameDisplay.blit(boardwin,(0,0))
            text = large_font.render(str(Team1Name)+" Wins!", True, black)
            gameDisplay.blit(text, [display_width/2, display_height/2])
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(5)
            gameDisplay.blit(background,(0,0))
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(5)
    elif Team2Point > Team1Point and Team2Point > Team3Point and Team2Point > Team4Point:
        Win = True
        win.play()
        while Win:
            gameDisplay.blit(boardwin,(0,0))
            text = large_font.render(str(Team2Name)+" Wins!", True, black)
            gameDisplay.blit(text, [display_width/2, display_height/2])
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(5)
            gameDisplay.blit(background,(0,0))
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(5)
    elif Team3Point > Team2Point and Team3Point > Team1Point and Team3Point > Team4Point:
        Win = True
        win.play()
        while Win:
            gameDisplay.blit(boardwin,(0,0))
            text = large_font.render(str(Team3Name)+" Wins!", True, black)
            gameDisplay.blit(text, [display_width/2, display_height/2])
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(5)
            gameDisplay.blit(background,(0,0))
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(5)
    elif Team4Point > Team2Point and Team4Point > Team3Point and Team4Point > Team1Point:
        Win = True
        win.play()
        while Win:
            gameDisplay.blit(boardwin,(0,0))
            text = large_font.render(str(Team4Name)+" Wins!", True, black)
            gameDisplay.blit(text, [display_width/2, display_height/2])
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(5)
            gameDisplay.blit(background,(0,0))
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(5)
    elif Team1Point == Team2Point or Team1Point == Team3Point or Team1Point == Team4Point or Team2Point == Team3Point or Team2Point == Team4Point or Team3Point == Team4Point:
        Win = True
        win.play()
        while Win:
            gameDisplay.blit(boardwin,(0,0))
            text = large_font.render("Tie Win!", True, black)
            gameDisplay.blit(text, [display_width/2, display_height/2])
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(5)
            gameDisplay.blit(background,(0,0))
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(5)
```

I tried defining Win using the following, but receive `TypeError: Win() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Team1Name'` error:

```
def Win():
    win.play()
    Win = True
    while Win:
        gameDisplay.blit(boardwin,(0,0))
        text = large_font.render(str(Team1Name)+" Wins!", True, white)
        gameDisplay.blit(text, [display_width/2, display_height/2])
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(5)
        gameDisplay.blit(background,(0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(5)
```

I don't receive that error my code creating the names and placing them on the screen:

```
def Team1(Team1Name,Team1Point):
    text = large_font.render(str(Team1Name)+": " + str(Team1Point), True, white)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, [10,10])
```

Thoughts on how I can clean this up? Maybe I've just been staring at my screen too long.

Comment: The syntax highlighter is suggesting that you not use `Uppercase` variable names.

Comment: You're trying to use the same name, "Win", to refer to a function and a boolean value at the same time.  There's definitely way too much code repetition going on here.  I think you might want to take some time to look at python dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. I needed to place the DEF items into my loop.

I also played a lot while talking out loud at work. It allowed me to realize how to clean my code. I also reduced users from 4 down to 2, since only 2 of the hardware I made years ago work.

I went from the above down to the following:

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
            gameOver = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                answer.play()
                BlinkLeftImage()
                Team1Answer()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_2:
                answer.play()
                BlinkRightImage()
                Team2Answer()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_h:
                Help()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                win.play()
                Win()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
```

I do have another question though now. Is there a way to anchor (the terminology may be wrong) a text blit?

Currently my code is:

```
def Team2(Team2Name,Team2Point):
    if display_width <= 800:
        text = small_font.render(str(Team2Name)+": " + str(Team2Point), True, red)
        gameDisplay.blit(text, [((display_width/4)*3),10])
    elif display_width <= 1200:
        text = medium_font.render(str(Team2Name)+": " + str(Team2Point), True, red)
        gameDisplay.blit(text, [((display_width/4)*3),10])
    elif display_width >= 1440:
        text = large_font.render(str(Team2Name)+": " + str(Team2Point), True, red)
        gameDisplay.blit(text, [((display_width/4)*3),10])
```

Which works just fine, sort of, but the text doesn't line up properly. I'm not sure if there is a way to auto scale objects in python. Guess that's my next endeavor!

Comment: Do you want to center the text, justify it, or align it to the left/right?

Comment: I'd like to center the text based on an image. I've played with creating my own "auto scaling", which works decent enough, but knowing how to actually center, left, right, or justify would be good to know!